# Custom batch size in GAN, pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

I am building a GAN with pytorch following the example of https://github.com/eriklindernoren/PyTorch-GAN/blob/master/implementations/gan/gan.py. The setting is the following:

- Generator: input 19, output 15x50
- Discriminator: input 15x50, ouput 1
- input dataset: 1000 samples of 15x50

My training process is the following

```
for epoch in range(2000):
    for i in range(1000):

        # Adversarial ground truths
        valid = Variable(Tensor([1]), requires_grad=False)
        fake = Variable(Tensor([1]), requires_grad=False)

        # Configure input
        real_series = Variable(torch.tensor(dataset[i,:,:])).float().to(device="cuda")

        # -----------------
        #  Train Generator
        # -----------------

        # Sample noise as generator input
        z = Variable(Tensor(np.random.normal(0, 1, 19)))
        
        # Generate the series
        gen_series = generator(z).float().to(device="cuda")

        # Loss measures generator's ability to fool the discriminator
        g_loss = adversarial_loss(discriminator(gen_series), valid)
        
        g_loss.backward()
        optimizer_G.step()

        # ---------------------
        #  Train Discriminator
        # ---------------------

        optimizer_D.zero_grad()

        # Measure discriminator's ability to classify real from generated samples
        real_loss = adversarial_loss(discriminator(real_series), valid)
        fake_loss = adversarial_loss(discriminator(gen_series.detach()), fake)
        d_loss = 0.5 * (real_loss + fake_loss)

        d_loss.backward()
        optimizer_D.step()
        
        # Output loss
        if i % 200 == 0:
            print(
                "[Epoch %d/%d] [Batch %d/%d] [D loss: %f] [G loss: %f] [real loss and fake loss : %f/%f] \n "
                % (epoch, opt.n_epochs, i, len(dadaset), d_loss.item(), g_loss.item(), real_loss.item(), fake_loss.item())
            )
```

**MY question and thoughts**
It is really slow. I later find out that in the [original example](https://github.com/eriklindernoren/PyTorch-GAN/blob/master/implementations/gan/gan.py), the code uses `torch.utils.data.DataLoader` to load the dataset, and there is a build-in `batch_size` parameter in the function setting. Then what should I do with my own example? I tried to use the functions
`from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader`, but the dimensions are always incorrect. Or how should I modify the double for loop?

**If you understand my questions above, feel free to ignore the following updates**

**Update**: As the comment suggested, the information of Dataset and DataLoader can be found at pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html.

**Update2**: I tried to use the two functions and got to the following

```
# Modify the dataset
import torch
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
  
# defining the Dataset class
class data_set(Dataset):
    def __init__(self):
        dataset = syndata
        self.data = dataset
  
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)
  
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.data[index]
    
    
dataset = data_set()
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size = opt.batch_size, shuffle=True)
```

and the training process became

```
for epoch in range(2000):
    for i, series in enumerate(dataloader):

        # Adversarial ground truths
        valid = Variable(Tensor(1000, 1).fill_(1.0), requires_grad=False)
        fake = Variable(Tensor(1000, 1).fill_(0.0), requires_grad=False)
        # Configure input
        real_series = Variable(series).float().to(device="cuda")
        print(real_series.shape)
        # -----------------
        #  Train Generator
        # -----------------

        # Sample noise as generator input
        z = Variable(Tensor(np.random.normal(0, 1, 19)))
        
        # Generate the series
        gen_series = generator(z).float().to(device="cuda")

        # Loss measures generator's ability to fool the discriminator
        g_loss = adversarial_loss(discriminator(gen_series), valid)
        
        g_loss.backward()
        optimizer_G.step()

        # ---------------------
        #  Train Discriminator
        # ---------------------

        optimizer_D.zero_grad()

        # Measure discriminator's ability to classify real from generated samples
        real_loss = adversarial_loss(discriminator(real_series), valid)
        fake_loss = adversarial_loss(discriminator(gen_series.detach()), fake)
        d_loss = 0.5 * (real_loss + fake_loss)

        d_loss.backward()
        optimizer_D.step()
```

This of course produces an error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-64652111ea5e> in <module>
     47 
     48         # Measure discriminator's ability to classify real from generated samples
---> 49         real_loss = adversarial_loss(discriminator(real_series), valid)
     50         fake_loss = adversarial_loss(discriminator(gen_series.detach()), fake)
     51         d_loss = 0.5 * (real_loss + fake_loss)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in __call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
    539             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    540         else:
--> 541             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    542         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
    543             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

<ipython-input-4-9bb24644e107> in forward(self, x)
     33     def forward(self, x):
     34         x = x.flatten()
---> 35         x = self.fc(x)
     36 
     37         return x

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in __call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
    539             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    540         else:
--> 541             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    542         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
    543             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/container.py in forward(self, input)
     90     def forward(self, input):
     91         for module in self._modules.values():
---> 92             input = module(input)
     93         return input
     94 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in __call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
    539             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    540         else:
--> 541             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    542         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
    543             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/linear.py in forward(self, input)
     85 
     86     def forward(self, input):
---> 87         return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
     88 
     89     def extra_repr(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in linear(input, weight, bias)
   1370         ret = torch.addmm(bias, input, weight.t())
   1371     else:
-> 1372         output = input.matmul(weight.t())
   1373         if bias is not None:
   1374             output += bias

RuntimeError: size mismatch, m1: [1 x 750000], m2: [750 x 32] at /pytorch/aten/src/THC/generic/THCTensorMathBlas.cu:290
```

The reason for this error is that in the original code, the input of the discriminator is 15x50 = 750. However, this Dataloader function inputs 1000x15x50. I really don't think that using the Dataset and DataLoader from pytorch is the right call, but I also have no idea how to get around it or how to set custom batch size by myself.

Comment: you should post relevant parts of your Dataset and DataLoader definition in code, otherwise its hard to understand dimension issues.

Comment: @ayandas Sorry, my bad. The information of these two functions can be found at https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html

Comment: What did you do with `Dataset` exactly? Please show some code.

Comment: can you post the error you get please.

Comment: I dont think you need the dataloader btw. it would be very easy to divide your dataset list and send batches of it to the model by list slicing.

Comment: @D.ACAR Yes! Exactly! But I have no idea how to do it. Could you write an example so that I can modify?

Comment: @Tab1e you can find good examples in the tutorial section of the website: [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/data_tutorial.html)

Comment: @Ivan If I was able to figure it out after watching the tutorial, I **would not** ask this question.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the late answer. can you try the following:
I am assuming that your dataset is a list of size 1000 which each element contains 50 list of size 15. if your dataset is flattened but still follows the dimensions you have given you may modify reshape the dataset while converting to numpy. `datset=np.array(dataset).reshape(-1, 50, 15)`

bs is batchsize

```py
dataset = np.array(dataset)
np.random.shuffle(dataset)
s = dataset.shape[0]
end = s // bs + (s%bs!=1)
for i in range(end):
    data = dataset[i*bs:(i+1)*bs,:,:] if i < end -1 else a[i*bs:,:,:]
```

then convert the data to a tensor and put it in device.